# How to send Email through a C++  program?

Tags: c++, email, gcc

How can I send an email from C++? Is there a good cross-platform (MS Windows, Linux etc) library that I can use? I'm using GCC (cygwin on MS Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jwSMTP - a cross-platform SMTP class.

http://johnwiggins.net/jwsmtp/

Answer (score 3):

Check out [C-Client](http://www.washington.edu/imap/)

- Apache license
- Very established library ( makers of Pine email reader, UW-IMAP Server, etc. )
- Supports IMAP, POP, SMTP, and NNTP
- Unix and Windows

Answer (score 2):

Look at [VMime](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vmime/).

> VMime is an all-in-one Internet mail library. This well designed, powerful C++ class library allows you to parse/build/modify MIME messages. With the messaging module, you can connect to POP3/IMAP/SMTP/Maildir very easily, and with the same code!